# axja call in success callback of first call only works when breakpoint is set

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootbox

I have an aps.net MVC Webpage incl. Bootstrap and some plugins. To delete a record I want to do a confirmation and for that I use the Bootbox plugin. After deleting (1st ajax call) I want to reload the page (2nd ajax call in case of success)

Actually, everything seems to work fine but the second call is only done, when I set a breakpoint in the browser and step in. Without it looks like that the second call is just skipped. I don't find any error mesage in Console.

Here is the code:

```
bootbox.confirm({
    title: 'Kategorie löschen',
    message: '<div class="text-center text-danger">Möchten Sie die Kategorie wirklich löschen?</div>',
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Ja',
            className: 'btn-success'
        },
        cancel: {
            label: 'Nein',
            className: 'btn-danger'
        }},
    callback: function (result) {
        if (result == true) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: '@Url.Action("CategoryDelete", "Admin")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { cid : catid },
                    success: function (delresult) {
                        if (delresult.success) {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '@Url.Action("CategoryList", "Admin")'
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            bootbox.alert({
                                title: 'Kategorie löschen',
                                message: '<div class="text-center text-danger">Die Kategorie konnte nicht gelöscht werden!</div>',
                                buttons: {
                                    ok: {
                                        label: 'ok',
                                        className: 'btn-default'
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }}
})
```

Due to being the first question I don't know if I need to provide any further information.
Ah, this happens in Firefox as well as in Chrome. In both browsers it works when a breakpoint is set.

So the question is: is there something wrong with the code even it seems to work or did I miss something else?

Any help and advice is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: "only works when breakpoint is set" Every time I see this, it's probably because you are using the value before the callback is called and this is caused by a lack of understanding in how asynchronous events work.

Comment: Maybe I don't really understand, when yu say "because you are using the value before the callback is called" but I think that I didn't. But yes, I'm not familiar with JS and even less with ajax.
But the answer of Tieson T. helped me, so it's fine to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to reload the page after your delete action, this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CategoryList", "Admin")'
});
```

doesn't do what you think it does. To reload the page, you need to set the page's [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location):

```
if (delresult.success) {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("CategoryList", "Admin")';
}
```

Or, just use the [reload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) function:

```
if (delresult.success) {
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: Actually I read in another question that I just can do another call to reload, but your answer helped me. 
But I think this is something I could have find out by myself by learning some basics of JS. So, sorry for asking that 'simple' question and thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Not sure what you may have read, but that's not how [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) works.